# android Combine 2 bitmaps without drawing them on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, reference, bitmap

my name is John and i have a problem.I need to make from 2 bitmaps 1 without drawing them on canvas.As i saw in may tuts online like this http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas they use canvas to capture the image.The reason that i dont want to draw them is because i need to use this bmp as referense to do some effects on other images.Thanks in advance.Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: When writing a question, please take your time. Avoid slang (like "tuts") and format your text properly (sentence case, single space after punctuation, etc.). Please edit your question accordingly. On topic: how do you want to combine two bitmaps? I mean, what would be equivalent process in Paint (or some other drawing tool)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I 100% understand the question but would it not be possible to create a clone of the Bitmap you need to reference for your effects. Then use the cloned Bitmap to draw on the canvas whilst retaining the reference to the original for use in your effects?

Hope this helps and sorry if I have missed the point of your question.

Comment: Do note that a clarification about the question can be done in the *comments*.

Comment: i need to create this bitmap first from 2 others and then do a reference :/

Comment: I am not an experienced programmer , i am not even noob ,but i can program somethings, so criter me too much what about i am going to suggest.Maybe there is a way to take the first bitmap colors and save them in array then take second and save them in other array and then aplies the small bitmap array to the second? or no?